# Have I understood the whole Incompleteness business correctly?

Tags: soft-question, proof-theory, incompleteness, first-order-logic

I am reading Gödel-Escher-Bach and a good dialogue by Eliezer Yudkowsky and I think I might have understood the nature of the Completeness and Incompleteness theorems (at least regarding Peano Arithmetic).

The Completeness Theorem tells us that any semantic implication can be syntactically derived in First Order Logic. The Compactness Theorem tells us that the axiom scheme of induction has a model, because every subset of it has models.

I know on authority that there exists “non-standard” numbers in first order PA and that if there exists a single non-standard such there must exist an infinity of infinite “successor chains” of non-standard numbers; one chain for each Rational and each chain being trivially isomorphic to the integers.

I am not quite sure how to prove that first order PA cannot disprove the existence of one non-standard number.

**Question 1:** What is a proof that first order PA cannot rule out at least one non-standard number?

Now, the Incompleteness Theorem states that in first order PA there exists a number which encodes — by an arbitrary formula encoding scheme — which is neither provable nor disprovable in first order PA.

As I understand it, this number is necessarily a non-standard integer, and given that first order PA cannot rule out it's existence, first order PA is incomplete.

**Question 2:** Is this explanation fullfilling?

Comment: I don't think you've given any basis for the claim "this number is necessarily a non-standard integer".  Non-standard vs. standard integer is a distinction external to first order PA, having to do with nonstandard models of arithmetic.  Also, for a given Goedel encoding, the numbered formula is constructed, so in principle an actual finite number may be derived for it.

Comment: @hardmath This is why I am asking a question. I don't havet much basis for my claims: I try to learn the whats before the wherefores of maths. Accepting proven truth and only later looking at the proofs. One of the proven truths I know is that First Order PA cannot deny the existence of nonstandard numbers at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Compactness Theorem tells us that the axiom scheme of induction has a model, because every subset of it has models.

It is true, as far as it goes, that **if** every finite subset of PA has a model, **then** the complete PA has a model. However, that in itself is not a very interesting observation, because essentially the only way we have to know that *every* finite subset of PA has a model is to point to the particular model $(\mathbb N,{+},{\times})$, which is already a model of all of PA.

For your **question 1**, the standard way to show that PA has models with nonstandard integers (if it has models at all), is this: Extend PA with a new constant letter $c$, and an infinitude of new axioms
$$ c\ne 0 \qquad c\ne S(0) \qquad c\ne S(S(0)) \qquad c \ne S(S(S(0))) \qquad \cdots $$
The extended theory satisfies the hypothesis of the compactness theorem -- every *finite* subset of its axioms has $\mathbb N$ as a model, because there can be only finitely many numbers its axioms say are *not* $c$. Therefore, the entire extended theory has a model, and because *all* of the axioms are true in the model, the interpretation of $c$ must be a nonstandard integer -- we're explicitly requiring that it is different from each of the *standard* ones.

For your **question 2**: No, that seems to be wrong. The Gödel number of the Gödel sencence is an ordinary standard number which we could compute with pencil and paper given sufficient time and determination. (This will be somewhat easier if we choose a more economical Gödel numering, but never mind that).

Because the Gödel sentence is undecidable, there must exist a model of PA in which this sentence has an encoded *proof*, and the Gödel number of *that* proof is necessarily a non-standard number.

Comment: Oh, so that is where the non-standard number comes in.